# Is there a way to get all modules 'under' a specific module in the hierarchy?

Tags: python, django, introspection

Is there a way of listing all python modules directly underneath a specified model in the hierarchy?

I've got a Django web-app that is slowly growing, and I've re-organised it based on this article:

http://paltman.com/2008/01/29/breaking-apart-models-in-django/

However, I'm trying to improve on his technique by making use of introspection in the module initialization file (__ init __.py) in order to auto-detect all instances of the Django model class in the subordinate jobs. I've got this sort of got this working, but it still needs a static list of modules in the tree above it to work.

In case people are interested, here's what my solution looks like:

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from sys import modules

moduleList = ['TechTree', 'PilotAbilities']
__all__ = []

for moduleName in moduleList:
  fullyQualifiedModuleName = '%s.%s' % (__name__, moduleName)
  moduleObj = __import__(fullyQualifiedModuleName)

  __all__ += [item for item in dir(moduleObj) if isinstance(getattr(moduleObj, item), ModelBase)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can get `os.path.dirname(parent.__file__)`, and then `glob.glob()` or `os.walk()` and look for other  **init**.py files.

Comment: A little bit clunky, but it may be the only workable option (given the lack of other responses).

Answer (score 1):

This is just an attempt, but it seems to work.  I'm running python 2.7.1 and dir(somemodule) gives me all associated modules.  Tested with the openpyxl and os modules.

```
def import_all(name):
    __import__(name)
    for i in dir(name):
        try:
            if type(i) == type(name):
                import_all(name+'.'+i)
        except:
            pass
```

Note:
This is probably extremely unpythonic and discouraged, but it seems to work.

Note 2:
That was because I accidentally had 'openpyxl' (a test I was using) instead of the list submodules.  Sorry

Comment: Oddly, when I try this I just get a list of the modules this object has imported (instead of the list of modules that exist beneath this in the 'tree').

Comment: Well, I've managed to find a different solution - so don't worry too mich about it. If you come up with something though, I'd be curious to hear it.

Comment: This should be fixed,  I'll do some testing